# Retreive a vNet IP Address Prefix on Azure using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I need to get the IP address prefix of a Virtual Network on Azure, here is the command I write:

```
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name "resources-vnet" -ResourceGroupName "resources"
$num = $vnet.AddressSpaceText
```

This gives me the following output:

```
{
"AddressPrefixes": [
"10.80.13.0/24"
]
}
```

What I need it to show is this:

```
10.80.13.0/24
```

I don't know how I can achieve it. I searched a lot both here and Google and did not find a way. I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `$vnet`?  It sounds like you need to 1. Parse the output of the cmdlet or 2. Figure out which member to access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try outputting the following:

```
$vnet.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes
```

Comment: This will only work if the member exists.  He'd have more luck with `$vnet.AddressSpace | Get-Member` first

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 ultimately you are right, but a vnet can't exist without at least one address prefix being defined.  A more robust solution would be to ensure the response had the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName 
$VnetLocation = (Get-AzVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).Location
$AddressPrefix = $virtualNetwork.AddressSpace.AddressPrefixes
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.